# Java Game - how to add enemies using Arraylist?

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I'm doing my first Java game using GdxLib, and I want to create enemies using an ArrayList (but I'm not sure of how to do it), and that all of them spawn in a random position, but i got few problems,

1. I'm creating them wrong cause they are spawning like a 'line' because I don't know how to spawn them randomly.
2. When any of my created enemies on Screen 'dies' (count == 20) if I shoot any other enemy I can't kill it.

Here is the class code:

```
public class World {

    gameMain game;
    Ship ship;
    ArrayList<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
    ArrayList<Follower> enemies = new ArrayList<Follower>(5);
    WorldRenderer wr;
    Iterator<Bullet> bIter;
    Iterator<Follower> eIter;
    Bullet b;
    Enemy e;
    int count = 0;
    int shipCount = 0;   
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    public World (gameMain game){
        this.game = game;
        ship = new Ship(new Vector2(20, 15), 1, 1, 0, 5f);//Ship Atributes
        for (int i= 0;i<5; i++){ //Creates 5 enemies
             enemies.add(new Follower(5f, 0, 1, 1, new Vector2(x,y)));

             x = x+2;
             y = y+2;

        }

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(this)); 
    }


    public Ship getShip(){
        return ship;
    }

    public ArrayList<Follower> getEnemies(){
        return enemies;
    }

    public void update(){
        ship.update();

        bIter = bullets.iterator();
        while(bIter.hasNext()){
            b = bIter.next();
            b.update(ship);
        }

        eIter = enemies.iterator();
        while(eIter.hasNext()){
            e = eIter.next();

            if(ship.getBounds().overlaps(e.getBounds()))
                Gdx.app.log(gameMain.LOG, "ColisioN!");
            shipCount = shipCount +1;
        }

        bIter = bullets.iterator();
        while(bIter.hasNext()){
            b = bIter.next(); 

            eIter = enemies.iterator();
            while(eIter.hasNext()){
                e = eIter.next();

                if(e.getBounds().overlaps(b.getBounds())){
                    Gdx.app.log(gameMain.LOG, "!");
                    bIter.remove();
                    count = count +1;
                    if (count == 20) {
                        eIter.remove();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void addBullet(Bullet b){
        bullets.add(b);
    }

    public ArrayList<Bullet> getBullets(){
        return bullets;
    }

    public void setRenderer(WorldRenderer wr){
        this.wr = wr;
    }

    public WorldRenderer getRenderer(){
        return wr;
    }

    public void dispose(){

    }
}
```

Also, I tried to put a `Thread.sleep(2000)` after an enemy creation to the next creation, but when I run the game the Screen freezes, but the thread is working because I used a `System.out.println` to print in console after each creation.
There is another option to delay the bucle without using `Thread.sleep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this little handy function should help you:

```
public float randFloat(float Min, float Max) {
    return Min + (float)(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1));
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    float x = randFloat(-50.0, 50.0);
    float y = randFloat(-50.0, 50.0);
    enemies.add(new Follower(5f, 0, 1, 1, new Vector2(x, y)));
}
```

Your `x` and `y` variables should not be global, but local to where you are creating the enemies. Also you do not need to specify the size of the `enemies` list when you declare it. In the code example above I just gave `-50.0` and `50.0` as min/max for `x` and `y`, in reality you should pass the bounds of your level/world.

> When any of my created enemies on Screen 'dies' (count == 20) if i shoot any other enemy i can't kill it.

I'm assuming `count` refers to the health of the enemy, in that you need 20 shots to kill an enemy. In that case, of course you cannot kill another enemy because you never reset the `count` variable! You keep incrementing it, but will it ever be 20 again? Do this instead:

```
if (count == 20) {
    count = 0;
    eIter.remove();
}
```

I hope that resolves your problems.

Comment: That worked! I really apreciate it :)
I got a last question if you dont mind, when an enemy touchs the Ship, the message 'Collision' is displayed, but if i want to remove the Ship after x values of times, what should i do?
In other words, what method should i implement in my Ship class to 'remove' it from screen?

Comment: Remove it from view or destroy it completely? Wouldn't you just check if `shipCount == x` like the enemies? My best guess would be `dispose()`, but that will destroy the entire entity, you'd probably want to write a custom function that destroys the ship's sprite but keeps its info intact.

Comment: I was able to remove it giving null value to the Ship, and next i created a new one. Now last thing that i noticed i need is how can i delay the ship 'death' for a few secods to insert a sprite; i tried using Thread.Sleep(--) but it's useless because the whole game sleeps till the time ends. Do you have any idea of what can i do?
Sorry in advance for asking you too many questions.

Comment: Haha it's no problem. What I would do is add a function, something like `kill()`, to the Ship class that plays your sprite anim when you call it, and the anim itself triggers the `dispose()` upon finishing.